# Navigation bar click links not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

**About the nav bar**
I have a nav bar that is not in the DOM of the document. That makes it difficult to change this nav bar a little bit for another place on my site where I want to add this as a HTML element. But I try to do it and I am almost there.
Because it is not in the DOM of the document I don't have source codes (only a huge jquery plugin file with many other things that has nothing to do with this nav bar), so I just copied this nav bar using the browsers' developers tools.

**Problems**
2 things are not working: When you click on a circle it should show a red small circle in it with the dark red color #800000. You can find this in the codes. It will not show up.
Problem 2: The nav bar links to elements with a specific ID, like e.g. firstPage, secondPage etc.. But I tested this bar on a page with elements with those IDs, but the nav bar does not link to those elements when you click on the circles in the nav bar. It does not lead the page to the place of those elements.

Does anybody have some tips what I miss or do wrong? Any solution is welcome. Doesn't matter if it's HTML / CSS / Jquery / Javascript.

Only HTML:

```
<div class="left" id="fp-nav-ios">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="#firstPage"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 1
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="#secondPage"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 2
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="#3rdPage"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 3
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="#page4"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 4
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="display: block;">
                <a href="#page5"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 5
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page6"><span></span></a>
                <div class="fp-tooltip left">
                    Page 6
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Jsfiddle including CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/9d5wd6xm/

Comment: I found your description of the problem very hard to understand:

1) Do I understand correctly that you found this navbar on some webpage and copied over html and css to your project?
2) In your JSFiddle there are no elements with appropriate ids - so clicking anchors will not get you anywhere.
3) Are you sure there is no JavaScript involved in making circles red?

Comment: I think the problem with the links that are not working can be solved if you put the `<a href="#firstPage">` inside the span. Because now the `<a>-tag` is not working for it is not inside the span you're clicking on and thus doesn't have a width or height.

Comment: A difficult to understand question, but a very simple solution. Thank you very much V.Boersch-Supan! That did the trick!

Comment: The <a> links problem is solved now. Only the red circle is not showing up. Anybody an idea? Yes, Olga, you understood it well. I don't know the specific Jquery codes for this nav bar, because the original Jquery file where it is part from, is much too complicated for me to see which codes need to let this nav bar work. So yes, some JS/Jquery is involved, but as you can see in the fiddle the red circles are found in the CSS under this line: #fp-nav-ios ul li a.active span,. This makes the circle red: background: #800000;. But it is related to the class name 'active', which is not found in HTML

Comment: So the only remaining question is: How to let that red round dot show up inside a circle that is (last) clicked?